# Trying to find a better way to sorting the data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

In my data frame I am trying to sort the data in descending order. I am using the below line of code for sorting my data and it works as intended.

```
CNS25VOL <- CNS25VOL[order(-CNS25VOL$MATVOL22), ]
```

However if I refer to the same column by it's index number, the code throws an error

```
CNS25VOL <- CNS25VOL[order(-CNS25VOL[, 2]), ]
```

Error thrown is

```
Error in CNS25VOL[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

While I do have a solution to what I am intending to do, but issue I see is if all of a sudden name of my column changes the code won't work. I know that their position will stay same in the data frame.

How can we handle it.

Comment: in the last line, it looks like there might be a typo in your code: `CNS25VAL[, 2]` instead of `CNS25VOL[, 2]`. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue apart from noting that potential typo.

Comment: Are you referring to the error message that I have posted @krfurlong

Comment: My error msg should have been ending in "VOL" and not "VAL" which I have edited.

Comment: what do you get if you run `str(CNS25VAL)`?

Comment: Apparently you expect `CNS25VOL[, 2]` to be a vector, because it would be a vector, were it a simple `data.frame`. It is probably a tibble so try `CNS25VOL[, 2, drop = TRUE]` instead. Note that even though tibbles are `data.frame`s they also behave differently at times.

Comment: It comes like this "tabyl [790 x 8] (S3: tabyl/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)" and then followed by description of individual columns.

Comment: The `tbl` in that indicates a `tibble`. Please try stating the `drop = TRUE` and if that does not solve the problem, post some reproducible example data for us to verify our proposals.

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard , Yes this works now. So now I have got a clue on what I should I have been doing instead.

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer so you can accept it and people will see that the problem has been solved.

Comment: It's already accepted @Bernhard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order(-CNS25VOL[, 2])` order here does expect a vector which you try to construct via the `[]` in `CNS25VOL[, 2]`. Normal dataframes will return a vector consisting only of the 2nd column. A `tibble` however will return a tibble with only one column.

You can reproduce the behaviour of normal `data.frame`s with the `drop = FALSE` argument to `[]` as in

`CNS25VOL[, 2, drop = TRUE]`

Try to always be aware whether you are using a standard `data.frame` or a `tibble` or a `data.table` because they look very similar and are not in the details. Also see https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html

`dplyr` functions tend to give you a `tibble` back even if you fed them a classical `data.frame`.

Comment: I take this as a correct answer. Out of curiosity, I have a similar dataframe where when I check it's STR, it comes as " int [1:790]. Will the same principle hold true for there as well?

Comment: It's probably easier to tell if you post the complete output of `str(...)` but that reads like the `str` of an vector of type `integer`.

Comment: I figured it @bernhard . I was so lost in figuring this out that I didn't notice that I hadn't run the code of my previous line and hence it was still an unassigned vector of type integer.